# How do I turn a string into an argument?

Tags: string, lua, arguments, lua-table

*I am using the app TouchLua.*

I need to turn a string from a table into an argument. This is the only way I would like to do the table.

```
b = {}
b[1] = "010,010,draw.blue"

function drawButtons()
   for i = 1,2 do
      draw.fillrect(tonumber(string.sub(b[i],1,3)), tonumber(string.sub(b[i],5,7)), tonumber(string.sub(b[i],1,3))+10, tonumber(string.sub(b[i],5,7)),string.sub(b[i],9))
   end
end

drawButtons()
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a function `eval` so that `print( eval( "draw.blue" ) )` is roughly equivalent to `print( draw.blue )`, here is a quick and dirty version:

```
local function eval( s, e )
  return assert( load( "return "..s, "=eval", "t", e or _G ) )()
end

-- global variable
draw = { blue = 2 }
print( draw.blue )
print( eval( "draw.blue" ) )
```

If you are using an older Lua version than 5.2, you will need `loadstring` instead of `load` and an additional `setfenv` call. Of course, instead of using `load` you can parse the string `s` and index the table `e or _G` manually.

The above code assumes that `draw` is a global variable. If you want the code to work with a local variable you need to use the debug library:

```
-- same for local variable
local localdraw = { blue = 3 }
print( localdraw.blue )

-- needs debugging information, so won't work with stripped bytecode!
local function locals()
  local t, i, n, v = {}, 1, debug.getlocal( 2, 1 )
  while n ~= nil do
    t[ n ], i = v, i+1
    n, v = debug.getlocal( 2, i )
  end
  return t
end
print( eval( "localdraw.blue", locals() ) )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try this later, and let you know. It's unfortunate that's there's no toargument() like there is tostring() or tonumber() !

Comment: `toargument()` wouldn't make much sense, since there is no type called "argument" in Lua. You can pass all values as arguments to functions. What you are trying to do is interpret a piece of code (which is a `string`) and pass its result as an argument.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is working as if it were a table. I should've made this clear, but draw is a library, and blue is a color for it. So draw.blue is a color for the library. I was able to use manual colors though, so thanks!